# How do I query a nested object in MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a JSON schema that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5692a3e124de1e0ce2dfda22"),
    "title" : "A Decade of Decadence, Pt. 2: Legacy of Dreams",
    "year" : 2013,
    "rated" : "PG-13",
    "released" : ISODate("2013-09-13T04:00:00Z"),
    "runtime" : 65,
    "countries" : [
            "USA"
    ],
    "genres" : [
            "Documentary"
    ],
    "director" : "Drew Glick",
    "writers" : [
            "Drew Glick"
    ],
    "actors" : [
            "Gordon Auld",
            "Howie Boulware Jr.",
            "Tod Boulware",
            "Chen Drachman"
    ],
    "plot" : "A behind the scenes look at the making of A Tiger in the Dark: The Decadence Saga.",
    "poster" : null,
    "imdb" : {
            "id" : "tt2199902",
            "rating" : 8,
            "votes" : 50
    },
    "awards" : {
            "wins" : 0,
            "nominations" : 0,
            "text" : ""
    },
    "type" : "movie"
}
```

I am trying to find a movie released in 2013, that is rated PG-13 and has won no awards. I tried the following query in my Mongo Shell but no luck:

```
db.movieDetails.find({rated: "PG-13", year:2013, awards: { wins : 0}})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> When the field holds an embedded document, a query can either specify an exact match on the embedded document or specify a match by individual fields in the embedded document using the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

```
db.movieDetails.find( { "rated": "PG-13", "year": 2013, "awards.wins" : 0 } )
```

Answer (score 0):

if this PG-13 rating query would work for you:

`db.movieDetails.find({"rated": "PG-13"})`

then i would try something like this:

`db.movieDetails.find({$and: [{"rated": "PG-13"}, {"year": 2013}, {"awards": { "wins" : 0}}]} )`

Comment: does this one without the awards work? `db.movieDetails.find({$and: [{"rated": "PG-13"}, {"year": 2013}]} )`